# What is a good sandal type of cycling shoe for summer riding?

Tags: product-rec, shoes

I am looking forward to the southern summer and was wondering if anyone could recommend a good sandal style cycling shoe (I have SPD pedals)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several companies that make sandals which are SPD compatible, even Shimano!

Unfortunately everything I've seen personally looks relatively dorky style-wise, but I'm sure someone offers a SPD compatible sandal that also looks cool.  Then again, some cyclists think their glove/short/jersey tan looks cool so YMMV... but I guess it would still look less dorky than wearing casual clothes and cycling shoes!

[Shimano sandal](http://bike.shimano.com/publish/content/global_cycle/en/us/index/products/shoes/mtb/product.-code-SH-SD66.-type-.html)

[Keen](http://www.keenfootwear.com/product/fw10/shoes/men/pedal/commuter)

[Bike Nashbar](http://bit.ly/bJZFH6)

Comment: The Shimano link is already broken - I tried http://www.shimano.com/publish/content/global_cycle/en/us/index/products/shoes/mtb/product.-code-SH-SD66.-type-.html and found the details.

Answer (score 5):

I bought a pair of Northwave Shark shoes this year which are SPD compatible and used them in the short British summer.  They have open vents on each side so are kind of sandal like.

Weird thing is that the site [www.northwave.com](http://www.northwave.com), only shows these in the PDF catalogue and not in the Product listing.

I had been looking for some time to get this style of shoe so grabbed them when I could.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go Simon: http://www.northwave.com/eu/shoes_det.php?itemid=464&catid=4&area=4

They look great!